# Proof that these ideals in an integral closure are principal

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

Let $K$ be the field $\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$, where $\theta^3 - 9\theta - 6 = 0$. Much of the heavy work has been done for us: we are given that $(2) = PQ^2$ and $(3) = R^3$ are the prime ideal decompositions of the ideals $(2)$ and $(3)$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$ respectively, so that $P = \langle 2, \theta \rangle$, $Q = \langle 2, \theta + 1 \rangle$, and $R = \langle 3, \theta \rangle$. *I want to prove that the ideals* $P$, $Q$ *and* $R$ *are principal ideals.*

---

I know that I need to show that $P$, $Q$ and $R$ are generated by a single element, say $a \in \mathcal{O}_K$, through multiplication by the elements of $\mathcal{O}_K$. Would taking each ideal in turn, assuming that they are not principal and seeking a contradiction be a valid way to proceed? Any hints for establishing a method to prove this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It sounds awkward to show something is principal by assuming it is not principal: how do you articulate the property that an ideal is *not* principal in a productive way? It almost sounds like proving a number is rational by assuming it is irrational. I'm not saying such an approach is always doomed, but doesn't it sound strange to you? Have you ever seen an ideal proved to be principal in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute norms of $\theta$, $\theta+1$, $\theta+2$, and $\theta+3$ and the result will follow from this information and the prime ideal factorizations of $(2)$ and $(3)$.

If you don't know how computing the norm of an algebraic integer $\alpha$ gives you information about the prime ideal factorization of the principal ideal $(\alpha)$ then you should read your algebraic number theory references more carefully.